# Samsung S5360 and Adobe AIR?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'm trying to run a compiled .APK file from AIR3 SDK but Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 keeps saying that it wasn't installed. Any thoughts? Are there hacks to make it work? If ever it wasn't supported natively?

Comment: did you installed air for android?

Comment: I am using the captive runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is not supported in your smartphone model. I had the same problem while trying to run my Flex 4.6 mobile app in Samsung Galaxy Y and Samsung Galaxy Ace. However, I works happily in my Samsung Galaxy SII as well as HTC Evo.

For the list of supported smartphone platforms, please go to the following link:
http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/smartphones.html

For AIR3 Tech Specs:
http://www.adobe.com/in/products/air/tech-specs.html

Hope it helps.